# How to manage chat with twilio channels in android

Tags: twilio

In am creating a chat application using twilio. Unlike Whatsapp, when destroying the created private channel from twilio programmatically it gets deleted from both users list. And also if someone created a chat channel with me and I am trying to delete channel, it says

> user unauthorized for this command

i.e only the user who created a channel can only delete the channel.
How to handle this delete thing?

Please someone suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If any user is able to delete their private channels, then you can give them the permission to, by adding the [`destroyChannel` permission](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/permissions) to the channel user role.

Alternatively, you could [destroy the channel using the server side REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/api/channels?code-sample=code-delete-a-channel&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x) once the users leaves.

Comment: But when the channel is destroyed by any user of channel (when permission is there to destroy )then it will be destroyed for all the users of channel.I want it to be like this
When the user deletes or leaves the channel,it should only be reflected to that particular user and that channel should be as it is for the user who hasn't deleted or left the channel,and again when channel is created with same user it should be a new channel for user who has deleted the channel and respectively the chat as well

Comment: Oh, so instead of deleting a channel, you should just have the user `leave` the channel: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/2.2.0/docs/Channel.html. That will retain the messages for the other user and doesn’t require extra permissions.

Comment: When user will rejoin the channel,all the old messages will again be loaded or  not ?

Comment: If you don't delete the channel, then the messages won't be deleted either. It's up to your application to load the messages.